# display the contents of a folder using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a folder that contains two files, I want to display the names of two file and when I added another file I display their name too. My question is, can I do that with Kafka?

Comment: How about you tell us what do you want to accomplish? What's the use case and why do you think Kafka is a good choice for your "problem"?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution in the field of big data to detect the presence of a new file in a well-defined directory. In our case this directory is our input. After detection I have to display the filename and his continue

Comment: How much of these files (in total) do you expect in a day?

Comment: they are files CSV generated by MSC of a telecommunications operator therefore about two or three millions a day

Answer (score 0):

Its strange case of use kafka. I think that this should by done adding an apache flume. Flume can pool directory and when discover new files, send this to kafka and then process this messages to recover file name.

it solves your problem?

Comment: I do not know how to do that, so I'm not sure he can solve my problem or not

Comment: @G.Saleh well, do you expect to get an answer that you already "know how to do"?

Comment: if I know that he is accomplishable with Kafka, I can work and I am sure that I will arrive